# Writing a backup script that can deal with both files, absolute paths and relative paths

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, backup

[image]

I am trying to write a backup script with a minimal number of commands. The backup script takes two inputs, the absolute OR relative path of destination where the the backup is to be made, and a an absolute OR relative path to the file or directory that needs to be copied. I am just starting out with Bash so I am a complete beginner. I can also use only a limited amount of commands to write the script, which are indicated in the picture.

To create the actual backup I will use the command
tar -czf $destination $whattobackup

As for how to deal with absolute and relative paths, i'm not sure how to proceed? What do I need to take into account that will handle both?

As for the other parts of the question, I have a rough idea of what to do (I have very beginner level experience with java) using conditionals but really don't know how to implement it given how confusing the bash syntax is. I've gone through a bunch of similar questions on unix.stackexchange but most of them seems to make use of utilities that I can't use for these questions/ or have a different context in which the script is backing up. I've spent at least 10 hours trying to crack this and can't make any progress. Can someone please help me understand how to proceed and what is really going keeping in mind that I'm a complete beginner?

This is what i've done so far. Is this correct?

`/backup.sh destination-path source-path`

```
d= $date + "%Y%m%d"  
archivename=basename $2 +"."+ "$d"+ ".tar"   
dest= $1  
tar cvf archivename $2 –
```

Comment: Work one step at a time. Start on point 1, just the 1st part (up to but not including farthermore). Get that working, and tested. Then add one more bit, continue along this path until done, or stuck.

Comment: `this is what I have so far. Is this correct?

/backup.sh destpath(where to put the file ) sourcepath(file or dir to backup)

d= $date + "%Y%m%d"

archivename=basename $2 +"."+ "$d"+ ".tar"  

dest= $1

tar cvf archivename $2`

Comment: @user140161 Please, include that in your question.

Comment: i've edited the question to include my work

Comment: I have tried to format to the best of my understanding, of what you have done. However you have not told us what the code does, and what step you are stuck on. You need to work one step at a time. This is my top tip, this is the only way that you can solve this problem. This is the difference between a novice and an expert. Experts work one step at a time.